# Add multiple columns to my dataframe (if statement)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, finance

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

| factor_A | factor_B | factor_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0384 | -0.0565 | 0.0964 |
| -0.0598 | 0.0967 | 0.9156 |
| 0.8795 | 0.0254 | -0.0853 |

I now want to create some new columns or a new df (factor_A_signal_A, factor_B_signal_B and so on)  with the following if statement:
If the factor_x is > 0, than 1, otherwise -1.

So far so good. But the problem is, that at the moment I don't know how many factors I will put into my dataframe and I can't do an if/else statement for example 100 columns.

Could you please help me? I need this step to multiply each factor with each signal.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the columns in your DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [0.1,-0.2,0.3],
    [-0.1,0.2,0.3],
    [0.1,0.2,-0.3]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['factor_A', 'factor_B', 'factor_C'])

for col in df:
    new_name = col + '_signal'
    df[new_name] = [1 if x>0 else -1 for x in df[col]]

print(df)
```

producing the following output

```
   factor_A  factor_B  factor_C  factor_A_signal  factor_B_signal  factor_C_signal
0       0.1      -0.2       0.3                1               -1                1
1      -0.1       0.2       0.3               -1                1                1
2       0.1       0.2      -0.3                1                1               -1
```

Answer (score 0):

On option would be [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) with a `rsuffix`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'factor_A': [0.0384, -0.0598, 0.8795],
    'factor_B': [-0.0565, 0.0967, 0.0254],
    'factor_C': [0.0964, 0.9156, -0.085]
})

signal_cols = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.gt(0), 1, -1), columns=df.columns)
df = df.join(signal_cols, rsuffix='_signal')
```

`df`:

```
   factor_A  factor_B  factor_C  factor_A_signal  factor_B_signal  factor_C_signal
0    0.0384   -0.0565    0.0964                1               -1                1
1   -0.0598    0.0967    0.9156               -1                1                1
2    0.8795    0.0254   -0.0850                1                1               -1
```

---

[`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) can be used if columns need to be *exactly* as outlined in the OP:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'factor_A': [0.0384, -0.0598, 0.8795],
    'factor_B': [-0.0565, 0.0967, 0.0254],
    'factor_C': [0.0964, 0.9156, -0.085]
})

signal_cols = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.gt(0), 1, -1), columns=df.columns)
signal_cols.columns = (
    signal_cols.columns
        .str.replace(r'factor_(.*)', r'factor_\1_signal_\1', regex=True)
)
df = df.join(signal_cols)
```

`df`:

```
   factor_A  factor_B  factor_C  factor_A_signal_A  factor_B_signal_B  factor_C_signal_C
0    0.0384   -0.0565    0.0964                  1                 -1                  1
1   -0.0598    0.0967    0.9156                 -1                  1                  1
2    0.8795    0.0254   -0.0850                  1                  1                 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your answer! After these signals I am now able to multiply each factor with each signal with the numpy.einsum method.

```
def one_one(n_factors):
    
    i, j = factors_table.iloc[:, 0:n_factors].shift(-1), factors_table.iloc[:, n_factors:5]
    factors_table['return_strategy'] = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', i, j) / n_factors # (i.values * j).sum(axis=1)
    return factors_table

factors_1_1 = one_one(2)
factors_1_1

factors_1_1['return_strategy'] = factors_1_1['return_strategy'].shift(1)
factors_1_1.head()
```

.. and gives me the following output:

[pandas df return strategy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0pKh.png)